# How to access nested array elements from Axios Response in console?

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js, axios, vuejs3

I am assigning an `array` from an `axios response` to the reactive `state object`. The `array` is assigned by `state.value.headings={...}` to the `state.headings` object, which is an `array` itself.

This is the `script element` from my `vue3 component`:

```
<script setup>
import {ref} from 'vue';

const state = ref({
    headings: {},
    content: {},
    image: "",
})

axios.get('/home')
    .then(res => {
        const data = res.data[res.data.length - 1]

        state.value.headings = {
            en: data['heading_(en)'],
            de: data['heading_(de)'],
            ar: data['heading_(ar)'],
        }
    })

console.log(state)
console.log(state.value)
console.log(state.value.headings)
console.log(state.value.headings.en)

</script>
```

This way I can access the content of `state` in this `vue3 component` like so:

```
<h2>{{ state.headings.en }}</h2>
```

But how do I access for example the `state.headings` array inside the `console`? I am trying to investigate `state` like so:

**`console.log(state)`**:

```
RefImpl {_shallow: false, dep: undefined, __v_isRef: true, _rawValue: {…}, _value: Proxy}
dep: Set(1) {ReactiveEffect}
__v_isRef: true
_rawValue: {headings: {…}, content: {…}, image: ''}
_shallow: false
_value: Proxy {headings: {…}, content: {…}, image: ''}
value: Proxy
[[Handler]]: Object
[[Target]]: Object
content: {}
headings: {en: 'Stutt:Ard', de: 'Stutt:Ard (de)', ar: 'شتوت أرد'}
image: ""
[[Prototype]]: Object
[[IsRevoked]]: false
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

**`console.log(state.value)`**:

```
Proxy {headings: {…}, content: {…}, image: ''}
[[Handler]]: Object
[[Target]]: Object
[[IsRevoked]]: false
```

**`console.log(state.value.headings)`**:

```
Proxy {}
[[Handler]]: Object
[[Target]]: Object
[[IsRevoked]]: false
```

**`console.log(state.value.headings.en)`**:

```
undefined
```

`console.log(state)` shows that `state.value.headings` carries the strings, that I want to access in the console but `state.value.headings.en` returns `undefined`. How can I target and output them in the `console`?

**Edit:**

Unfortunately from the outputs I have pasted, the parent/child relationships of the objects cannot be seen. The parent/child relationship of the object I'm after is `state.value.headings.en`.

**Edit2:**

Investigating `console.log(state.value.headings)` does not uncover the content of the `headings` object but it should be somewhere in there? I don't understand the `Proxy` object yet.

Comment: axios is asynchronious, so the log statements at the current position will always be the state how you created it and not when the axios response updated it. Put the log statement in the `then` and you should see the value. Also, if you use `reactive` instead of `ref` as I mentioned in your other question, you don't need the `.value` part.

Comment: Thank you, your input is very valuable :-)

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call . As for proxy, check the contents of [[Target]] . You can always flatten it with JSON stringify/parse, if it's JSON-compatible.